# not a single group ? oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want get the department_id ,how many employees in the each department, and also the sum of employees in the each department / all the employees.

This is my answer:

```
select department_id,em_count,emp_count/sum(emp_count) dep_precentage 
from 
(SELECT department_id, count(*)emp_count 
FROM employees 
group by department_id);
```

However , It shows it was not a single group.Can you please help me to fix it? 
Appreciate!

Comment: try pulling the `GROUP BY`to outside the inner select

Comment: what are you trying to do? emp_count / sum(emp_count) will always be 1...

Comment: Yes,I found that.I want the sum of employees in the each department / all the employees.  So  how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are some AS keywords missing + add group by, try this:

```
    SELECT department_id,
  em_count,
  emp_count/SUM(emp_count) AS dep_precentage
FROM
  (SELECT department_id,
    COUNT(*)       AS emp_count
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department_id
  ) GROUP BY department_id , em_count
```

Comment: `AS` is optional for column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use `SUM()` as an analytic/window function:

```
SELECT department_id, emp_count, emp_count/SUM(emp_count) OVER () AS dep_percentage
  FROM (
    SELECT department_id, COUNT(*) AS emp_count FROM employees
     GROUP BY department_id
)
```

That way you avoid a second GROUP BY.